# Area calculation in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, area

So I haven been trying to calculate the total land loss due to climate change. The dataset that I use is from this website [link](https://www.cresis.ku.edu/content/research/maps)

This dataset consists of the longitude and latitude of the place that will most likely be lost. I want to calculate the total area of such points. I know the geosphere packages has a function to calculate the area of the polygon created by a set of points. Still I worry that using this may overestimate the result by connecting points that are really far away from each other.
[link to map](http://sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)
If you look at the Antarctica, simply connecting all the red points would overestimated the affected area.

My question is does the areapolygon() function accounts for that fact? If not is there a way to come up with a more precise estimate for the area in question? I was thinking about using the distance between points as a criteria. But I don't know how to implement that in R.

Thank you

This is the code i have been using so far

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    library(geosphere)
    library(plyr)
    grid_file_6m <- new("GDALReadOnlyDataset","link_to_the_file")
    grid_6m <- asSGDF_GROD(grid_file_6m, output.dim=c(1000, 1000))
    plot(grid_6m,bg="black")
    grid_6m_df <- as.data.frame(grid_6m)
    grid_6m_df=grid_6m_df[,-1]
    grid_6m_df$id= coords2country(grid_6m_df)
    grid_6m_df<-grid_6m_df[!(is.na(grid_6m_df$id)==TRUE),]
   grid_6m_df<-grid_6m_df[!(is.na(grid_6m_df$x)==TRUE),]
   grid_6m_df<-grid_6m_df[!(is.na(grid_6m_df$y)==TRUE),]
   write.csv(grid_6m_df,"test.csv")
   grid_6m_df<- read.csv(file="test.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE )
   Allname<-levels(grid_6m_df$id)
  Country.df <- split(grid_6m_df[,-4],grid_6m_df$id)
  clean.up<- function(x)
  {
   x<-x[,2:3]
   }
   Country.df <-lapply(Country.df,clean.up)
   distm.km <-function (x)
  {
   distm(x)/1000
  }
   dis.table <-lapply (Country.df,distm.km)
```

The function coords2country() is from another post here to match which country a point belongs to.

Thank you

Comment: Looking the data, I do not understand why you want to connect all the red point. For me it would make more sens to estimate the area of a "point", and multiply by the number of point.

Comment: @timat How can you calculate the area of 1 point then? I thought of it before but figured out it wouldn't make sense to calculate the area of just 1 point.

Comment: you have to make an estimation.. the best would be to ask the people which made the map, what is exactly representing 1 point on the map.. because as it make no sense to calculate the area of 1 point, it make no sens to say that a point will be submerged.. only an area can be submerged ..